# How do the sets have similar properties?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, contest-math

[image]

Where they say:

> "Assume that we have sets $S_k$ with the desired properties for all $k < n$ (line 4 in solution)"

- What properties are they talking about?

> They said: "Let $S_n = \{2a : a \in S_{n/2} \}$

- What is $S_{n/2}$? They haven't even defined it!!
- What does $a \in S_{n/2}$ even mean?

Comment: The proof is by induction on the "index" $n$ of the "family" of sets $S_n$. The property used for the induction is a property of sets : "whose elements are each of the form ..., no elements ..., and the elements ...". You have to show the *base cases* i.e. that $S_0$ and $S_1$ has the requested property and then, assuming that all sets $S_k$ has the desired property, for $k < n$, you have to prove that also $S_n$ has the property. Having done that, you can apply the "induction rule" concluding that all the $S_n$ have the property.

Comment: $S_{n/2}$ is "defined" from $n=2$ on; i.e. $S_2 = \{ 2a : a \in S_1 \}$ and so on. Having proved that $S_1 = \{ 1 \}$, $S_2 = \{ 2a : a \in S_1 \} = \{ 2a : a = 1 \} =  \{ 2 \}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that for all $k<n$ we already defined $S_k$. So $k=n/2$ is generally a number such that $k<n$. So $S_k$ was defined, and so defining $S_n=\{2a\mid a\in S_k\}$ is fine.

Comment: So, $$S_2 = \{2a : a \in S_1 \}$$ so then how is $$S_1 = 1$$ (+1)

Comment: You ***define*** $S_1=\{1\}$. You don't somehow derive this from the definition; moreover $1$ is not an even integer, so we don't use this definition for $S_1$ anyway.

Comment: Thanks! So: $$S_2 = 2$$ Then:

$$S_4 = \{ 2a: a \in S_{2} \} = 4$$

So this is saying $$S_n = n$$? How does it help with the proof?

Comment: First of all, $S_n$ is not defined like that for odd integers (although it might be $n$ as well). Secondly, if you proved that $S_n=\{1,\ldots,n\}$ for all $n$, and for every $n$ the set $S_n$ has the property that all its elements have this property... then every integer has this property.

Comment: How can $S_n$ have more than one element? As $S_{n/2}$ will only have one element?

Comment: If you check out how $S_n$ is defined for odd $n$ you might just find out!

Comment: but $S_n$ only exists for even $n$?

Comment: If you continue reading past the fourth line, you might learn otherwise.

Comment: Sorry Asaf, you did good help! I need to first focus on even $n$.  Can you tell me?

-What is the induction hypothesis? And what they are proving (for the even $n$)?

Comment: Again. The induction hypothesis is that $S_k$ was defined *for all* $k<n$. Then $S_n=\{2a\mid a\in S_{n/2}\}$, and they claim that if $S_k$ is such that all the elements of $S_k$ can be written in that form, then $S_n$ has this property as well.

Comment: When you say:

"$S_k$ is such that all elements of $S_k$ can be written in that form." 

What do you mean, which form? 

Also doesnt induction have assume $P(k)$ is true then prove $P(k+1)$ is true? What is this doing here?

Comment: I think  it is here: http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h64429p383273 Kent's solution. What is the induction hypothesis there (explicitly)? And where is $P(k+1)$?